# loading Text from csv using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to load a CSV file to an array with numpy
the CSV file has 2 columns that look like this

```
Cities:   Population
Boston     122
New York   152
Michigan   158
```

when I try to load it with this code

```
data = np.loadtxt(file_name)
```

it gives me an error, is there a way to load it and isolate the strings and the numbers?

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: city name
```

Comment: Nice of you to share the error with us so we can help .... oh wait. No Error? Dont post a picture of your error. Copy and paste its text and edit your question with it. Thanks

Comment: I understand that its trying to convert the city names into a float and it cant do it, I want to load only the numbers and I am not sure if its even possible

Comment: Is the data always going to be in the second column with the first row being skipped?

Comment: yes, this is the format it will always look like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certain arguments that can be passed to `numpy.loadtxt` namely, `usecols` and `skiprows` which can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

Therefore you can use these to get only the desired rows/columns you want. Using your small example csv file the code becomes:

```
data = np.loadtxt('filename.csv', delimiter=",", skiprows=1, usecols=1, dtype=int)
print (data)
# [122 152 158]
```